# i) If b is real, prove that $|a^b| = |a|^b$ $a\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

i) If b is real, prove that $|a^b| = |a|^b$ $a\in\mathbb{C}$
also,
ii) Is it true that $|a^b|$ = $|a|^{|b|}$   for all $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$

My solution for part 1:

**Update** It has been pointed out to me that $a^b$ is not uniquely defined, and is multi-valued, and I agree with that. However, can we demonstrate that each value of $a^b$ has the same modulus and in that case, $|a^b|$is a well defined number, and then proceed from there. If this is valid, do my computations hold true? If not, how do I fix them?

Consider,
 $a^{b} = exp(b.log(a))$

$\Rightarrow a^{b}=exp(b.log(a)+ b(arg(a) +2\pi k)i)$

$\Rightarrow a^{b}= |a|^b.exp(b(arg(a) +2\pi k)i)$ (say $k := (b(arg(a) +2\pi k) $)

then, $ a^{b}= |a|^b.(cos(k)+isin(k))$

and, $ |a^{b}|= ||a|^b|.|(cos(k)+isin(k))| = |a|^b $

Is my approach correct?

So for part (2) based on the comments, would it be valid to choose a counter example.

say, $a = 2$ and $b = -2$ and clearly, $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$
clearly, $|2^{-2}| = \frac{1}{4} \neq |2|^{|-2|}$

Would this suffice?

Comment: The horror, the horror... Re i), note that $z^w$ is not defined for general numbers $z$ complex and $w$ real (already $i^{1/2}$ does not exist as a complex number, right?). Re ii), note that even if $a$ is real positive and $b$ real (in which case $a^b$ is well defined, the identity you suggest can fail.

Comment: Thanks. I get your comment about part (ii). But I have a question about your remark on part (i), I don't think  I understand you completely. sorry.

Comment: What is your question about my remark on (i)? Note that "I don't think I understand completely" is not a question.

Comment: From my understanding, $z^w$ is multivalued. It will be single valued if w is an integer, will take q values if w = p/q were p, q are co-prime and will have infinitely many values if w is irrational. But, can't we still prove the relation (or disprove it) in the question? Also, where exactly is the flaw in my steps?

Comment: Indeed, "multivalued" is a polite way of saying that there is no canonical way to define a function $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, $z\mapsto z^w$ (except when $w$ is an integer). "can't we still prove the relation (or disprove it) in the question?" You will have noted that the LHS of "the relation in the question" involves $a^b$. If, by chance, every sensible definition of $a^b$ was leading to the same value $|a^b|$, one could hope to show the identity $|a^b|=c$ for some well defined $c$. But this ain't so (as your own computations more or less show). Ergo.

Comment: Sorry, I have a follow up question: even though $a^b$ may not be uniquely defined, and take on multiple values, won't all of them have the same modulus. Thus, can't we say that $|a^b|$ for any real b, is still defined?

Comment: Funny, *this is answered in my previous comment*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) Let $b$ be an integer. $a\in\mathbb{C}$ can be rewritten $a=|a|e^{i\theta}$, so that $a^{b}=|a|^{b}e^{ib\theta}$, hence $|a^{b}|=|a|^{b}|e^{ib\theta}|=|a|^{b}$.

ii) It is clear that if $b=-1$ and $a=2$, $|a^{b}|=|2^{-1}|=1/2\neq|a|^{|b|}=2$

Comment: the question specifically asks for b real, not be an integer.

Comment: Yes, but as stated above, $i^{1/2}$ is not well defined because it has two possible "values". For example, the complex square roots of $i$ are defined as the solutions $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $z^{2}=i$, i.e. $z=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi)}$ ($k=0,1$). In a more general sense, the $n$-th roots of a complex $\rho e^{i\theta}$ are defined as the solutions $z^{n}=\rho e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: So it cannot be proved for b real (in general)? Also, I understand your steps, they are a whole lot simpler than my working, but could you give it a look over and point out a mistake?

Comment: The problem is that we talk about the module of one complex number and $a^{1/2}$ is not a complex number, it's, in some sense, two complex numbers. If you write $i^{2}$, it has one single value. If you write $i^{1/2}$, it is not well defined, so I don't think this assignment is rigourous for $b\notin\mathbb{Z}$. I mean since $z^{2}=1$ has the solutions $1$ and $-i$. So, if you write $\text{"}i^{1/2}\text{"}\times \text{"}i^{1/2}\text{"}=1\times (-i)\neq 1$, it has no sense at all.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your explanation, I have a follow up question: even though $a^b$ may not be uniquely defined, and take on multiple values, won't all of them have the same modulus. Thus, can't we say that $|a^b| $ for any real b, is still defined?

Comment: I understand what you say and this is right: the $n$-th roots will have the same module. But you should define another definition of the modulus, in some sense, because the modulus is a function defined on complex numbers and $a^b$ is not always defined as a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Assuming $a,b\in\mathbb{R^+}$:

$$\left|\left(ai\right)^b\right|=\left|\left(ae^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}\right)^b\right|=\left|\left(a^b\cdot e^{\frac{b\pi}{2}i}\right)\right|=\left|a^b\right|\left|e^{\frac{b\pi}{2}i}\right|=\left|a^b\right|=|a|^b=a^b$$

---

Assuming $a,b\in\mathbb{R^+}$:

$$\left|\left(-ai\right)^{-b}\right|=\left|\left(ae^{-\frac{\pi}{2}i}\right)^{-b}\right|=\left|a^{-b}\cdot e^{-\frac{(-b)\pi}{2}i}\right|=\left|a^{-b}\right|\left|e^{\frac{b\pi}{2}i}\right|=\left|a^{-b}\right|=|a|^{-b}=\frac{1}{a^b}$$